# Why does gradle download two copies of gradle and how do I prevent it?

Tags: gradle

My `GRADLE_USER_HOME` is set to `c:\gradle`. Android Studio has created `C:\gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-bin\88n1whbyjvxg3s40jzz5ur27` with a copy of gradle v2.2.1, but when I run `gradlew.bat` from the command line, a new folder `C:\gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-bin\3rn023ng4778ktj66tonmgpbv` is created with the exact same files. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I have different Gradle Distributions/Versions, but only in the
C:\Users\MyUsername.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.3-bin
I have 3 Distributions.

Maybe it can come from different Versions of the `gradle-wrapper.jar` in the Gradle Wrapper Folder.

Following some Information about the Gradle Wrapper:

In the directory `gradle/wrapper` parallel to your `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat` file is the gradle wrapper jar and a `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.
In this `gradle-wrapper.properties` file you define the distribution Url i.E.

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip
```

to your remote gradle distribution for initial download.
There are `-bin` an `-all` gradle Versions.
See http://services.gradle.org/distributions

If you have an other Place of a `gradlew` with an other `gradle-wrapper.properties` file with a different `-all` or `-bin` Definition
and / or different Versions of the `gradle-wrapper.jar`,
then maybe you will get two different gradle distributions downloaded.

Prevent it: Only define one same gradle distribution and `gradle-wrapper.jar`.